# How do I make line charts overlay over bar charts in chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using leighquince fork of [chartjs](https://github.com/leighquince/Chart.js) in v1.01-beta.5 because I can overlay two charts.

When I try to overlay a line chart and a bar chart, the line chart is under the bar chart

[image: Bar overlays Line]

I can't seem to find an option that makes the Line chart be over the bar chart but `overlayBars:true`

How can this be achieved, will I edit the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be solved if you use the current master (instead of the one tagged v1.01-beta.5) - you don't need to set any options.

---

Fiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/n7jgo7oh/

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I managed to overlay the Line graph over the Bar. Before I have problems of getting the right source/commit of the fork since I'm using bower, and I can't seem to include the master. But I handled it with using the single file install of bower since you use rawgit on the fiddle. `"Chart.js": "https://rawgit.com/leighquince/Chart.js/master/Chart.min.js"`

Comment: That's good to know! By the way, I'd linked to the development version link. You might need to use the production link for more stability (even though you just use it when running bower). Just head over to https://rawgit.com and paste the raw GitHub url. Cheers!

Comment: any working fiddle? or update your answer with code please

Answer (score 6):

You have to declare the line chart first in the dataSet and then the bar chart:

```
datasets: [
        {
          type: 'line',
          yAxisID: 'y-axis-1',
          fill: false,
          pointRadius: 0,
          label: 'Nota media',
          backgroundColor: '#ed7d31',
          borderColor: '#ed7d31',
          data: [60, 59, 80, 81]
        },
        {
          type: 'bar',
          yAxisID: 'y-axis-0',
          label: 'Observaciones',
          backgroundColor: '#5b9bd5',
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39]
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your source you are defining and drawing line before bar try to invert definition and drawing: bar first then line

Comment: yeah, I declare the Bar data then Line on the datasets definition, but still the line renders under the bar.