# ChartJS 2.9.4 can't overlay line data on Horizontal Bar chart

Tags: chart.js

We have an issue where we can not overlay multiple graph types on top of each other with ChartJS 2.9.4 . We have narrowed this down specifically to `HorizontalBar` chart types.

I can't see what's wrong with the script code below, but the ChartJS persists in not showing anything when any `line` type is added. The current dual `horizontalBar` work perfectly.

Also frustratingly ChartJS seems to show by default to show no errors or notice information at all in any way to the console.

## Solution attempts :

- Lots of rearranging of layout, including ordering of `data` array.
- Confirming all options and settings.
- Putting "type" data in different areas (Chart/datasets/data)
- Reading lots of Stack Overflow on vaguely related issues
- Finding that the system **does** work with `'bar'` rather than `'horizontalBar'`
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693635/how-do-i-make-line-charts-overlay-over-bar-charts-in-chartjs)
- Changing "drawing order"
- Making it default to "line" and then setting `HorizontalBar` as the exception value (set within the data array)

## Aim:

[image]

## Code:

```
<script>
    Chart.platform.disableCSSInjection = true;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("historicChart");
    var historicChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: "horizontalBar",
            data: {
                labels: ["Mar 2017","Mar 2016","Mar 2015","Mar 2014","Mar 2013","Mar 2012","Mar 2011"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        type: "line",
                        label: "Visits",
                        data: ["3", "4", "1", "5", "6","0"],
                        pointBackgroundColor: '#FFC900',
                        pointRadius: 8,
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                        showLine: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Applicants",
                        data: ["2","4","5","8","9","4","3"],
                        backgroundColor: "#436B94",
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Intakes",
                        data: ["1","1","0","1","3","0","1"],
                        backgroundColor: "#C40500",
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 1
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    );
</script>

<div class='graphbox'>
     <h3>Applicants & Intakes over time</h3>
     <canvas id="historicChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They fixed this issue in v3 so upgrading to that is 1 solution, the other one is downgrading to version 2.8, in a git issue on their repo someone posted a workaround but that only works till version 2.8.

V3:
HorizontalBar has been removed as a type, use bar chart instead and set the index axis to `y` in your options

Example:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        type: 'line',
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y'
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

V2 solutions, for if stuck on v2 with plugin support
To achieve this in 2.8 you will have to specify your data as objects and specify the x and y coordinates

Example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Clients Signed",
      data: [2, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 5, 3, 10]
    }, {
      label: "Quota",
      data: [{
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q2 2015'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q3 2015'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q4 2015'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q1 2016'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q2 2016'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q3 2016'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q4 2016'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q1 2017'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q2 2017'
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 'Q3 2017'
      }],
      type: 'line'
    }],
    labels: ["Q2 2015", "Q3 2015", "Q4 2015", "Q1 2016", "Q2 2016", "Q3 2016", "Q4 2016", "Q1 2017", "Q2 2017", "Q3 2017"]
  },
  options: {
    barPercentage: 1.0,
    categoryPercentage: 1.0
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="myChartDiv">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@2.8.0/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Git issue: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4096

Comment: Thanks. Eventually we have updated to V3.2 and used the new system to replace HorizontalBar (Y-axis labels) and that works now.

Comment: If you can rephrase your answer slightly just so that upgrading is the preferred approach (and that `horizontalBar` chart type was removed. Horizontal bar charts can be configured using the newer [`indexAxis`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) option) that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working with v3, didnt really specify it indeed since most people who specify they are still working on v2 is because they need plugins that arent updated yet :)

Comment: Yeah we found workarounds for plugins and felt it's always better to update anyway, the Q was just to see if I'd missed something on the 2.9.4 setup. Cheers